Complex probability equation for simulations
I am trying to develop a probability equation using intersection notation that represents the proportion of times (on average) a random variate exceeds a lower threshold value $\beta_j$ or an upper value $\alpha_j$ during $J$ $(j=1,2,\ldots,J)$ sequential experiments within $I$ $(i=1,2,\ldots,I)$ simulations.  During each experiment, a random variate $U_j=j \times U(0,1)$ is drawn, and if $U_j>\alpha_j$ then the probability of success is accumulated.  There is also a probability of failure, which occurs if $U_j<\beta_j$. (the following constraint is always true: $\alpha_j>\beta_j$).  Note that $U_j$ is purposely not equal across each set of $J$ experiments, since $U_j=j \times U(0,1)$. In addition, $J \ll I$.
Below is the pseudocode for determining the success and failure probabilities for J experiments repeated numsim=$I$ times.  An important point is that as soon as $U_j<\beta_j$ or $U_j>\alpha_j$, the internal loop is exited.  Therefore, probabilities are only summed at the first occurrence when $U_j<\beta_j$ or $U_j>\alpha_j$.
for i = 1 to numsims
   for j = 1 to J
    U_j = j * U(0,1)
    if U_j < beta(j) then
      failprob = failprob + 1/numsims
      exit for
    endif
    if U_j > alpha(j) then
      succprob = succprob + 1/numsims
      exit for
    endif
   next j
next i

Obviously, the inner loop will continue only if $(\beta_j  \leq  U_j \leq \alpha_j)$ is true, whereas the outer loop is never exited.
The following equation I believe will capture the probability of success for the simulations:
\begin{equation}
P(Success) = \left. \sum_{i=1}^{100} \textrm{Prob} \left( \bigcap_{j=1}^J (\beta_j  \leq  U_j \leq \alpha_j) \bigcap U_j > \alpha_j \right) \right/ 100.
\end{equation}
where the first (leftward) intersection symbol needs to be used which represents not failing or not succeeding in order to make it to the $j$th experiment -- while the intersection symbol on the right is needed to represent when a success occurs:
In light of the above equation, I believe the notation below is not correct for representing the probability of success:
\begin{equation}
P(Success) = \left. \sum_{i=1}^{100} \textrm{Prob} \left( \bigcap U_j > \alpha_j \right) \right/ 100.
\end{equation}
My question is: doesn't there need to be notation that reveals that the simulations are exited when either $U_j<\beta_j$ or $U_j>\alpha_j$ are true?  I think exiting at first occurrence is represented by use of $(\beta_j  \leq  U_j \leq \alpha_j).$
Now, if I wanted, for example, the probability of success(failure) at the $k$th experiment, then I believe the succprob variable would need to be subscripted like succprob(j) and used as follows
for i = 1 to numsims
   for j = 1 to J
    U_j = j * U(0,1)
    if U_j < beta(j) then
      failprob(j) = failprob(j) + 1/numsims
      exit for
    endif
    if U_j > alpha(j) then
      succprob(j) = succprob(j) + 1/numsims
      exit for
    endif
   next j
next i

and the probability of success at the $k$th experiment would be (using a conditional symbol)
\begin{equation}
P_k(Success) = \left. \sum_{i=1}^{100} \textrm{Prob} \left( \bigcap_{j=1}^J (\beta_j  \leq  U_j \leq \alpha_j) \mid U_k > \alpha_k \right) \right/ 100.
\end{equation}
However, I don't know if an intersection is more appropriate than a conditional operator, as in
\begin{equation}
P_k(Success) = \left. \sum_{i=1}^{100} \textrm{Prob} \left( \bigcap_{j=1}^J (\beta_j  \leq  U_j \leq \alpha_j) \bigcap U_k > \alpha_k \right) \right/ 100.
\end{equation}
but don't know if it's okay to use an intersection symbol, $\bigcap$, in this scenario without a subscript on it.
NOTE:
Firstly, the pseudocode for the simulations is correct.  The post seeks the probability equation that represents the simulation.
Second, when e.g. $P_k(success)$ is of interest, since $U_1 \neq U_2 \neq U_3$, then $P_1 \neq P_2 \neq P_3$.

The break is out of the inner loop only. So exit for is similar to break in C in that only the current loop is exited, not the outer loop.  The outer loop is never broken out of.

You seem to want to find the probability of at least $3$ sequential cases of exceeding $\alpha$ in your $J=100$ iterations, subject to something about $\beta$ which I do not understand.  But you do not seem to have $3$ in your code.

@Henry - it won't be 3 sequential cases during each iteration, since the inner loop is exited as soon as any criteria is true.   Assume J=3 and numsim=100 in the code.

@Mike Earnest, if only (⋯) is used, how does the probability equation reveal the instruction to replicate the J=3 experiments 100 times? What's inside (⋯) is only 3 experiments. Regarding e.g. success, the contents of (⋯) will only be 0 or 1 for each set of J=3 experiments. FYI, the inner loop for j never has subscripts for i, i.e., which simulation is taking place.

Each simulation has three possible outcomes:

Success
Failure
Neither success nor failure

The probability of neither success nor failure is the simplest to consider. It is the probability that none of the $J$ experiments result in a success or failure:
$$p(N)=\prod_{j=1}^J\frac{\alpha_j-\beta_j}{j}$$
The probability of a success on experiment $k>1$ is the probability that no successes or failures occurred during the first $k-1$ experiments times the probability of success on experiment $k$:
$$p(S_k|k>1)=\Big(1-\frac{\alpha_k}{k}\Big)\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{\alpha_j-\beta_j}{j}$$
Summing the above probabilities along with the probability of success on the first experiment gives the probability of success for a single simulation replication:
$$p(S)=1-\alpha_1+\sum_{k=2}^J\Big(1-\frac{\alpha_k}{k}\Big)\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{\alpha_j-\beta_j}{j}$$
The probability of failure is found similarly:
$$p(F)=\beta_1+\sum_{k=2}^J\frac{\beta_k}{k}\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{\alpha_j-\beta_j}{j}$$
Demonstrating in R:
(seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 918102107
set.seed(seed)

J <- 10
k <- 1:J

# simulate alpha and beta values
alpha <- rbeta(J, 8, 0.5)*k
beta <- rbeta(J, 0.5, 8)*k

# calculate the probabilities of success, failure, or neither
ab <- cumprod((alpha - beta)/k)
pS <- sum((1 - alpha/k)*c(1, ab[-J]))
pF <- sum(beta/k*c(1, ab[-J]))
pN <- ab[J]

# verify the probabilities sum to 1
pN + pS + pF
#> [1] 1

# simulation using `rbinom`
I <- 1e5
Nsim1 <- rbinom(1, I, pN)
Ssim1 <- rbinom(1, I - Nsim1, pS/(pS + pF))
Fsim1 <- I - Nsim1 - Ssim1

# simulation using loops
Ssim0 <- Fsim0 <- 0L
for (i in 1:I) {
  for (j in 1:J) {
    U <- j*runif(1)
    if (U < beta[j]) {
      Fsim0 <- Fsim0 + 1L
      break
    }
    if (U > alpha[j]) {
      Ssim0 <- Ssim0 + 1L
      break
    }
  }
}
Nsim0 <- I - Ssim0 - Fsim0

# summarize the results
data.frame(
  res = c("pN", "pS", "pF"),
  True = c(pN, pS, pF),
  sim0 = c(Nsim0, Ssim0, Fsim0)/I,
  sim1 = c(Nsim1, Ssim1, Fsim1)/I
)
#>   res      True    sim0    sim1
#> 1  pN 0.2593731 0.25937 0.25978
#> 2  pS 0.4019998 0.40194 0.40110
#> 3  pF 0.3386271 0.33869 0.33912


Try this: make a vector of candidate sample sizes for each experiment using $n_j$.   Then initialize $J=1$, $n_j = 150$, $\mu_1 = 132.86$, $\mu_2 = 127.44$, $\sigma_1 = 15.34$, $\sigma_2 = 18.23$, $\delta = \mu_1 - \mu_2$,
$\sigma = (\sigma_1 + \sigma_2)/2$.  During simulations, increment successes if $Z>1.96$, where $Z = \delta \sqrt{n(j) / 2} / \sigma + ranZ$.   When the sample size is 150 for each group, the power, or your $p(S)$ should be near 0.79 or 0.8.  This is a simulation for power of a Z-test for equality of two means, where the $\alpha_j$ is now $Z_{\alpha j}$.

What you've described is very different from your original question. So much so that I believe it constitutes a different question entirely. It should be clear from the # simulation using loops portion of my R script that it is a faithful implementation of the pseudocode in your question. What would the pseudocode for your actual problem look like?

I'm not confident enough that I follow. I can try to update the answer (or answer a new question) if you can provide the complete pseudocode (or better yet, actual code) for the simulations.

I accepted the solution as an answer.   Will let you know if I add a question that extends the pseudocode provided in the OP.

I posted a new question just now. located here:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4950474/probability-equation-for-simulations-of-sequential-experiments
