Probability equation for simulations of sequential experiments
I am trying to develop an equation for the probability of success(failure) among $J$ sequential experiments involving an exposure and control group.  At the beginning of each experiment, a batch of $n_j$ objects is added to each group $(n_1=n_2=\cdots = n_J)$.  At the end of each experiment, a 2-group hypothesis test is performed for equality between two means (assume equal sample sizes and variances) using a cumulative statistic that's compared with failure and success boundary limits.  Success or failure can only occur once or never among the $J$ sequential experiments.  Boundary limits differ over the sequence of experiments.  The process of simulation replicates the sequence of experiments to gain a handle on success or failure.
Below is the pseudocode for determining the success and failure probabilities for J experiments repeated numsim times.  An important point is that as soon as the cumulative test statistic $T_j<\beta_j$ or $T_j>\alpha_j$, the internal loop is exited.  Therefore, probabilities are only summed at the first occurrence when $T_j<\beta_j$ or $T_j>\alpha_j$.
Initialize:
numsims = 100,000
J = 3, n(J), beta(J), alpha(J), mu1 = 132.86, mu2 = 127.44, sigma = 15 
delta = mu1 - mu2  

vector values:
n(1:3) = 50,50,50
beta(1:3) = -4,-3,-2
alpha(1:3) = 4,3,2

Simulate:

for i = 1 to numsims
   T = 0
   for j = 1 to J
      Z = delta * sqrt(n(j)/2) / sigma + rnorm
      T = T + Z 
      if T < beta(j) then
        failprob = failprob + 1/numsims
        fprob(j) = fprob(j) + 1/numsims
        exit for
      endif
      if T > alpha(j) then
        succprob = succprob + 1/numsims
        sprob(j) = sprob(j) + 1/numsims
        exit for
      endif
   next j
next i

The following equation I believe will capture the probability of success for the simulations:
\begin{equation}
P(Success) = \left. \sum_{i=1}^{100000} \textrm{Prob} \left( \bigcap_{j=1}^J (\beta_j  \leq  T_j \leq \alpha_j) \bigcap T_j > \alpha_j \right) \right/ 100000.
\end{equation}
where the first (leftward) intersection symbol needs to be used which represents not failing and not succeeding in order to make it to the $j$th experiment -- while the intersection symbol on the right is needed to represent when a success occurs.  In light of the above equation, I believe the notation below is not correct for representing the probability of success:
\begin{equation}
P(Success) = \left. \sum_{i=1}^{100000} \textrm{Prob} \left( \bigcap T_j > \alpha_j \right) \right/ 100000.
\end{equation}
My question is: doesn't there need to be notation that reveals that the simulations are exited when either $T_j<\beta_j$ or $T_j>\alpha_j$ are true?  I think exiting at first occurrence should be represented in the equation by use of $(\beta_j  \leq  T_j \leq \alpha_j).$
I also believe the probability of success at the $k$th experiment would be (using a conditional symbol)
\begin{equation}
P_k(Success) = \left. \sum_{i=1}^{10000} \textrm{Prob} \left( \bigcap_{j=1}^J (\beta_j  \leq  T_j \leq \alpha_j) \mid T_k > \alpha_k \right) \right/ 100.
\end{equation}
However, I don't know if an intersection is more appropriate than a conditional operator, as in
\begin{equation}
P_k(Success) = \left. \sum_{i=1}^{100000} \textrm{Prob} \left( \bigcap_{j=1}^J (\beta_j  \leq  T_j \leq \alpha_j) \bigcap T_k > \alpha_k \right) \right/ 100.
\end{equation}
but don't know if it's okay to use an intersection symbol, $\bigcap$, in this scenario without a subscript on it.

It looks like you have $T_j$ for $j \in {1, ..., J}$, rather than $T$. Your current notation seems wrong b/c you cannot have both $T\leq \alpha_j$ and $T>\alpha_j$. I think you mean $${Success}= {T_1>\alpha_1} \cup  \left(\cup_{j=2}^J \left({T_j>\alpha_j}\cap \cap_{s=1}^{j-1}{\beta_s\leq T_s\leq \alpha_s}\right)\right)$$  I think you are using $100000$ i.i.d. runs to estimate, so the probability does not change with $i \in {1, ..., 100000}$. But if you want to define $Success_i$ you can, so $P[Success_i]$ is the same for all $i \in {1, ..., 100000}$, then also use $T_{i,j}$.

I just edited because I know $T$ had to be subscripted as in $T_j$.

I noticed you relocated advancing to the next experiment ${\beta_s \leq T_s ≤ \alpha_s}$ when $j>1$ b/c it doesn't apply to $j=1$.   I believe your equation is for only for one set of $J$ experiments -- so don't you need to sum over 1E5 and then divide by 1E-05 somewhere? $P[Success_i]$ varies over $i$ because of the random drift of the test statistic (Z-score) at each experiment due to the added random $N(0,1)$.  So what's the equation for average $P[Success_k]$ at the $k$th experiment when ${\beta_j ≤  T_j ≤ \alpha_j }$ is true from experiment $j=1$ to $k-1$ over all the simulations?

I see your code resets $T=0$ for each new $i$. Also, it seems to me that your $Z$ variable depends only on $j$ and uses statistically i.i.d. Gaussians $rnorm$ on each usage. So, I do not see how the probability structure of the problem changes with $i$. It looks like you have a situation of i.i.d. experiments for each $i \in {1, ..., 10^5}$. If so, while some $i$ have success and others don't, $P[Success_i]=P[Success_1]$ for all $i\in {1, ..., 10^5}$. So define $X_i=1$ if $Success_i$ is true, and $X_i=0$ else, then ${X_i}_{i=1}^{10^5}$ are i.i.d. $Bern(p)$ with $p=P[Success_1]$.

So you immediately get $E[\frac{1}{10^5}\sum_{i=1}^{10^5} X_i]=p$ and $Var(\frac{1}{10^5}\sum_{i=1}^{10^5} X_i) = \frac{p(1-p)}{10^5} \leq \frac{1/4}{10^5}$. The variance can also be viewed as the mean square error between the uknown value $p$ and your estimate $\frac{1}{10^5}\sum_{i=1}^{10^5} X_i$. You can also get confidence intervals.

Thanks for the comments!   Someone proposed the following $P[Success]$ for all experiments after $j$ as $P_{k}=\sum_{j=k+1}^{J} P(\bigcap_{s=k+1}^{j-1} (\alpha_s \leq T_s ≤ \alpha_s) \bigcap T_j > \alpha_j)$, but I believe it's erroneous.

I realize, on average, the probability at any $j$th experiment within any $i$th iteration would be equal assuming large sample approximation (e.g. convergence) at an infinitely large value of $I$.  However, I am also interested in the equation for average prob of success over 1E5 iterations for e.g. the second experiment when $j=2$ -- which I am calling $P_k[Success]$ in the latter pair of equations, or in this case $P_2[Success]$.

Your previous comment does not make sense. I have no idea what you mean by "large sample approximation" or "infinitely large value of $I$." In fact I do not know what $I$ is.

Define $S_{i,j}$ as the event that there is a success at iteration $i \in \{1, ..., 10^5\}$ and stage $j \in \{1, ..., J\}$. Define the event $Successs_i$ by
$$Success_i = \cup_{j=1}^J S_{i,j} \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., 10^5\}$$
Observe that this is a disjoint union because (focusing on iteration $i$), if a success occurs at stage $j$ then it cannot occur at another stage $s \in \{1, ..., J\} \setminus\{j\}$. So
$$P[Success_i] = \sum_{j=1}^JP[S_{i,j}] \quad (Eq. 1)$$
Also
\begin{align}
S_{i,1}&= \{T_{i,1}>\alpha_1\} \\
S_{i,2} &= \{\beta_1\leq T_{i,1} \leq \alpha_1, T_{i,2}>\alpha_2\}\\
S_{i,3} &= \{\beta_1\leq T_{i,1}\leq \alpha_1, \beta_2\leq T_{i,2}\leq\alpha_2, T_{i,3}>\alpha_3\}\\
& \cdots \\
S_{i,J}&= \{\beta_1\leq T_{i,1}\leq \alpha_1, ..., \beta_{J-1}\leq T_{i,J-1}\leq \alpha_{J-1}, T_{i,J}>\alpha_J\}
\end{align}
This is equivalently written for a general $i,j$ by
$$S_{i,j} = \{T_{i,j}>\alpha_j\}\cap\left(\cap_{s=1}^{j-1}\{\beta_s\leq T_{i,s}\leq \alpha_s\} \right) $$
where for notational convenience, when $j=1$ we define $\cap_{s=1}^0\{\beta_s\leq T_{i,s}\leq \alpha_s\}=\Omega$ (the sample space).
Also, each iteration $i\in \{1, ..., 10^5\}$ simulates a multi-stage experiment with the same probability structure as all previous multi-stage experiments (that is, all multi-stage experiments $a$ for which $a<i$). The multi-stage experiment for iteration $i$ has no dependence on the multi-stage experiments at iterations $a \in \{1, ..., i-1\}$. It follows that
$$Success_1, Success_2, ..., Success_{10^5}$$
are mutually independent and identically distributed events. So there is some value $p \in [0,1]$ such that
$$P[Success_i] = p \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., 10^5\} \quad (Eq. 2)$$
If you like, for each $i \in \{1, ..., 10^5\}$ you can define
$$ X_i = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \mbox{if $Success_i$ is true} \\
0 & \mbox{else} 
\end{array}\right.$$
Then $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{10^5}$ are i.i.d. $Bern(p)$ random variables. Rather than mathematically calculating the value of $p$, it is standard to approximate $p$ via simulation using the random variable
$$ M = \frac{1}{10^5}\sum_{i=1}^{10^5}X_i$$
Notice that $M$ is the output of your computer program (you are calling it "succprob" instead of $M$).
It is easy to compute the mean and variance of $M$, and to obtain confidence intervals that illuminate how close $M$ is to the value of $p$.

Similarly, if we fix $j \in \{1, ..., J\}$ we have that
$$ S_{1,j}, S_{2,j}, ..., S_{10^5,j}$$
are mutually independent and identically distributed events, so there is a $p_j\in[0,1]$ such that
$$P[S_{i,j}]= p_j \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., 10^5\} \quad (Eq. 3)$$
and we can again approximate $p_j$ by simulation (you are currently doing this with your variable $sprob(j)$).  Just introduce the Bernoulli random variables $X_{i,j}$.
Using Equations (2) and (3), the Equation (1) reduces to
$$ p=p_1+p_2+...+p_J$$

Your simulation should verify that $succprob=\sum_{j=1}^Jsprob(j)$. I am a bit worried that your simulation does not initialize $succprob$ or $sprob(j)$ to zero, so just make sure to properly set the initial conditions. The way a program responds to undefined initial conditions is platform dependent (it can vary depending on the computer you use, or the software you use). Some software sets undeclared initial conditions to zero, other software sets it to whatever value was stored in its memory location before program execution. Good practice is to set the intial values to what you want them to be, rather than assume the software knows what you want. This practice is also useful to avoid errors when cutting and pasting your program for use as a subroutine in a larger program, because you do not know how many times the larger program will run your subroutine.

In the code, sprob(j) will keep a sum of success probability during the $j$th experiment over all $i$ iterations.   You reference ${Success_i}$ for the $i$th iteration, but what's the equation for sprob(j), which I'm calling $P_k$, which would be your ${Success_j}$?

I have updated my answer to define $S_{i,j}$ as the event we get a success at iteration $i$ and stage $j$.

Thanks for the rewrite of the answer.  Of course $succprob$, $failprob$, $sprob(j)$, and $fprob(j)$ are all zeroed before each set of simulations.  Operationally, I wouldn't invoke use of the large $1 \rm{E}5$ $ ×J$ array $S_{ij}$, since individual values of $S_{ij}$ aren't used and would involve too many calls to the memory register per element.

Using analogous borrowing from statistical randomization tests, there is notation for the number of times something occurs, which could be e.g. $P_{j>0}=#\left {b,j: (T_j^{(b)} > \alpha_j ) \bigcap \bigcap _{k=0}^{j-1} (\beta_k \leq T_k^{(b)} \leq \alpha_k )\right } / B$, where $B$ is commonly used for the number of iterations, and $\beta_j$, $\alpha_j$, and $T_j$ are zero-based arrays.

Yes. In my notation your $P_{j>0}$ value is what I might call the random variable $M_j$, defining it for a given $B$ (such as $B=10^5$) by $$M_j=\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^{B}X_{b,j} \quad\forall j\in{1,…,J}$$ where $X_{b,j}$ is the Bernoulli random variable that is 1 if and only if $S_{b,j}$ is true. So $X_b=X_{b,1}+…+X_{b,J}$ for all iterations $b$ (which again uses the fact that at most one index $j$ has success per iteration $b$) and likewise $M=M_1+…+M_J$. Here, $\beta_j$ and $\alpha_j$ values are given nonrandom constants, while $T_j^{(b)}$ a random variable.

Thanks, your answer is quite helpful.
